# Passing Date Document Completed into a Custom Salesforce Date Field

Tags: docusignapi

I can't seem to figure out how to pass the Date the Document is Completed into a custom Salesforce field to make reporting easier.  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for having this sit a week without answering.

I think the simplest way to do this would be to write an APEX trigger that takes the "Completed" date field from the DocuSign Status object and populates it into the custom object (or field) that you want to report on.